# Devise remember fails on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

currently anytime we deploy our app we all get logged out of the app, and have to sign back in using devise + rails 3.

Our deployment process is

Load balancer points to an EC2 instance (prod)

we push the new code to a new ec2 instance to test it out, and then switch the load balance to the new ec2 instance.

Then we all get kicked out of the app, and have  to sign back in.

Any ideas why that is?

Thanks

Comment: curious if you ever found a solution to this.  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: Having the same problem with sorcery remember_me_token

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store your session data? If you are storing that in the database, then check your deployment steps. Maybe you are cleaning up the sessions table in one of the deployment steps and that is logging everyone out.